# How redux thunk calls curried async thunk functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

My apologies if there is a question similar to this on StackOverflow, but after 3 hours of searching I couldn't find one.

I'm attempting to learn Redux and get past beginner proficiency with ReactJS and have the following thunk function:

```
export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
try{
    dispatch({ type:PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST })
    const { data } = await axios.get('/api/products/') 
    dispatch({ type:PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data })

}catch(error){
    dispatch({
        type:PRODUCT_LIST_FAIL,
        payload: misc_data_here
    })
}}
```

This function gets called in another file within a `dispatch` function with the relevant code as follows:

```
function HomeScreen() {

const dispatch = useDispatch()
const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList)
const { error, loading, products } = productList

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(listProducts())
    
}, [dispatch])

return (rest of UI...]
```

My question is as follows:

How exactly does `listProducts` get called in this case by redux? It would need to be called like `listProducts()(dispatch function here)` if my (poor) understanding is correct. How exactly does the thunk (`async (dispatch)`) get fed the dispatch function and what actually gets returned by the `listProducts` function into the `dispatch` call within `HomeScreen()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redux doesn't call your `listProducts` action creator, you do, when you dispatch the action. The thunk redux middleware checks if the action value is an object, i.e. like a normal action object, or a function. If it is a function then the middleware invokes the curried function and passes the `dispatch` and `getState` functions so the asynchronous logic is handled and any further actions can be dispatched.

[How does the middleware work?](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks#how-does-the-middleware-work)

> The actual implementation of the thunk middleware is very short - only
> about 10 lines. Here's the source, with additional added comments:
>
> Redux thunk middleware implementation, annotated
>
> ```
> // standard middleware definition, with 3 nested functions:
> // 1) Accepts `{dispatch, getState}`
> // 2) Accepts `next`
> // 3) Accepts `action`
> const thunkMiddleware =
>   ({ dispatch, getState }) =>
>   next =>
>   action => {
>     // If the "action" is actually a function instead...
>     if (typeof action === 'function') {
>       // then call the function and pass `dispatch` and `getState` as arguments
>       return action(dispatch, getState)
>     }
>
>     // Otherwise, it's a normal action - send it onwards
>     return next(action)
>   }
> ```
>
> In other words:
>
> - If you pass a function into dispatch, the thunk middleware sees that it's a function instead of an action object, intercepts it, and calls
>   that function with (dispatch, getState) as its arguments
> - If it's a normal action object (or anything else), it's forwarded to the next middleware in the chain

[See also the Redux Async data flow](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#redux-async-data-flow) for a great animated visual explanation.

Comment: So the thunk middleware in other words equivalently calls `listProducts(dispatch, getState)`? Wouldn't that return the anonymous inner async function?

Comment: @user3491700 No, the middleware calls the action value, the returned function from `listProducts()`, i.e. the `async (dispatch) => { ....`. You are invoking `listProducts` when you dispatch it, i.e. `dispatch(listProducts())`, and the return value is the "inner function" as you are calling it. Because the middleware sees the function, it invokes it, passing the new arguments.

Comment: yay, someone's actually reading and linking the new thunk docs page I wrote! :)